# Problem Installing Gazebo from debian

Tags: ros, gazebo, installation, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

Forgive me if this is a very simple beginners mistake, I am likely just missing something obvious.

After having installed ROS and been through the tutorials, my next task is to get the PR2 simulator up and running so that I can start playing with simulated robots to learn more about ROS.

I have found the Gazebo tutorial here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/StartingGazebo

But am running into a problem with the following command:
~$ rosdep install gazebo_worlds

Warning: could not identify ['gazebo_worlds'] as a package

So I tried installing teh Gazebo stack (in case it was missing) and this is what I get:
~$ sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-simulator_gazebo

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-diamondback-simulator_gazebo

I am running Ubuntu 10.10, have checked my PATH (it is set as per the ROS tutorials) and am still left scratching my head.

Your help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10065/problem-installing-gazebo-from-debian/) by [funk_e](https://answers.ros.org/users/460/funk_e/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2011-05-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-05-25**:
when doing apt-get install, replace all underscores with dashes, i.e. sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-simulator-gazebo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer my own question (for the benefit of anyone else that might run into this):

Some of the packages had not installed correctly.

I redid the installation of diamondback_desktop_full to pick up any missing packages that I had assumed were there and then used synaptic package manager to install the Gazebo packages I was after.

All commands now work :-)

---

Originally posted by [funk_e](https://answers.ros.org/users/460/funk_e/) with karma: 16 on 2011-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-06-09**:
Remember to be careful about under scores versus dashes '_' vs '-'  In debian packages they are different than the ROS name.  (switch to dashes)